# Contract Type is Not Attributed with ServiceContractAttribute

Tags: c#, wcf, servicehost

When trying to create an application that uses dynamic ports, instead of a hard-coded port value, I ran across this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException:  The contract type MLITS.Pulse.Pulse is not attributed with ServiceContractAttribute.  In order to define a valid contract, the specified type (either contract interface or service class) must be attributed with ServiceContractAttribute.

My code that is having issues follow:

```
public static void DynamicAddress()
{
    int sessionIdentification = 0;
    int portNumber = 0;
    int newPort = 0;
    string uriString = string.Empty;

    sessionIdentification = Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId;
    portNumber = 14613;
    newPort = portNumber + sessionIdentification;

    uriString = "net.tcp://localhost:" + newPort + "/PulseService";

    Uri uri = new Uri(uriString);

    //ServiceHost objServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Pulse), uri);

    ServiceHost objServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Pulse));
    objServiceHost.Description.Endpoints.Clear();
    objServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Pulse), new NetTcpBinding(), uri);

}
```

The commented out section is what I had before; however, I realized I needed to clear the Endpoints set up in the config file; which is why the later code exists, and where I am having troubles.  The reason for the config files is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431175/collection-already-contains-address-with-scheme-net-tcp), in another question that I had posted to help solve the problem I was experiencing before.  Once I find a solution I will post my results on both question and close them.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, and know how to fix the error I am receiving?

Comment: The error seems pretty explanatory.  Is `Pulse` or the interface decorated with the `[ServiceContract]` attribute?

Comment: Exactly.WCF requires atleast one `ServiceContract`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like your ServiceContract attribute isn't in your concrete class, try this.

```
ServiceHost objServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Pulse));
objServiceHost.Description.Endpoints.Clear();
objServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPulse), new NetTcpBinding(), uri);
```

Comment: seems that using was all i needed